# Exception while moving files

Tags: c#, file, move

Hey so lately i've been trying to move files from one folder to another but errors keep coming up.
Both the loacation and destination folders are created, location has few .txt files

Here's what i've tried:

```
string path = @"C:\TESTmove\path";
string path2 = @"C:\TESTmove\destiny";

if (Directory.Exists (path)) 
{
    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path)) 
    {
        File.Move (filename, path2);
        //Console.WriteLine (filename);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong place");
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Have you checked that the file does not exist in the destination before moving it?

Comment: The second parameter in `File.Move` should be the full path including filename, not just the destination directory.

Comment: @WalterWhite For examples of lots of file/directory operations have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc148994%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: There are not files in the "destiny" folder. i dont want to overwrite anything, just need to move the files in a folder "from a to b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the same file named "destiny" in the directory path "C:\TESTmove". *(That's not what you want, but that's basically what the code you posted is going to do.)*

Instead, include the filename when moving the file to the new location.

```
File.Move(filename, Path.Combine(path2, Path.GetFileName(filename)));
```

Comment: "destiny" is the destination folder

Comment: well the Directory.GetFiles() give the whole file path, not just the file name, so the Path.Combine thingy didn't work. i guess thats way :P

Comment: btw can i use it like this:
Path.GetFileName(filename).Contains(".jpg" || ".png");

Mostly the part with (".jpg" || ".png").

Comment: its like `Path` can get anyting :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong, you are saying:

```
string path2 = @"C:\TESTmove\destiny";
string filename = @"C:\TESTmove\path\test1.txt";

File.Move (filename, path2);
```

path2 should contain the path and the filename.

e.g. It should be like so

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\TESTmove\path\whatever.txt";
string destinationFile = @"C:\TESTmove\whatever.txt";

System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

There is no magic involved, File.Move needs to know what file you are moving to what file (not just location).

Comment: Directory.GetFiles() gives the whole path of the files e.g. when printing "filename" the output is:
C:\TESTmove\path\test1.txt